# how to setup user accounts on large network

Tags: networking

I am migrating a set of 20 computers to Ubuntu and will be having only this OS. The previous OS needs to be discarded along with all its associated headaches and dependencies. I have so far managed to install Ubuntu Precise and need help in setting up the user accounts.

The users would need access to shared folders on other computers as well as a network storage device. How to create users on the individual computers which will allow this? 
Also I require a single administrative (root / other) login for all the computers.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

20 computers is not a large network, it's tiny :)

Anyway, you'll want to look at:

- [ldap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer) for authentication
- [NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto) for sharing files
- [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com) for managing configuration of this on all computers (and other things, like the default rootpassword)

All these are rather large subjects, not really suitable for a single answer. So I'll leave you with those links, that should help you get started. Good luck!